# Showing a set is a manifold

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How do I show that the set $X$ of $2$ by $3$ matrices of rank $1$ is a manifold?  I tried defining the function $F(x_1,...,x_6) = (x_1x_4-x_2x_3,\space x_3x_6-x_4x_5)$ and letting $X = \{(x_1,...,x_6):F(x_1,...,x_6)\} = (0,0)$, but I'm having trouble showing that the total derivative of $F$ is onto for all points in $X$.

Comment: I that that the map ought to go from $\mathbb{R}^6 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, where $6 = 2 \cdot 3$ and $3 = \binom{3}{2}$ is the choice of *pairs of columns.*

Comment: As it's written, a matrix such as $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \in X$ even though it has full rank.  (I'm assuming that variables are numbering down the columns, from left to right.)